# How do I convert a .cer file to a PKCS#12

Tags: linux, openssl, certificate, pki

I have a .cer file. With that .cer (lets call it "dcba.com.cer") file I would like to create a pkcs#12 file. How can I do that using open SSL within the Linux command line?

Comment: You also need a private key corresponding to the certificate to do that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).